# Prolog determinant of matrix (recursion)

Tags: prolog

For example, in math, if you want to calculate the area of a triangle characterized by three point `A(1,2) B(3,4) C(5,6)`, the formula is:

```
|Ax  Bx| |Bx Cx| |Cx Ax|                   
|Ay  By| |By Cy| |Cy Ay|
```

In this case:

```
|1  3|  |3  5|  |5  1|
|2  4|  |4  6|  |6  2|
```

`1x4-2x3+3x6-4x5+5x2-1x6 = 4-6+18-20+10-6 = 0`

How can I use recursion of list in prolog to do this?

```
?- calculateAreaTri( [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], A).
```

Thanks (I prefer recursive predicate).

Comment: The points (1,2),(3,4),(5,6) are a  line and not a triangle.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What does this question have to do with figuring out the determinant of a matrix with recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, those 3 points do not generate a triangle (they are aligned). Anyway, you can compute the area with this predicate (intentionally easy and filled with syntactic sugar):

```
calculateAreaRectangle([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],A):-
    compute([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[1,2]],0,A).

compute([[_,_]],S,S).
compute([[A,B],[C,D]|T],S,TO):-
    write(A),write('*'),write(D),write('-'),write(B),write('*'),write(C),write('='),
    S1 is ((A*D) - (B*C)),
    writeln(S1),
    ST is S1 + S,
    compute([[C,D]|T],ST,TO).

?- calculateAreaRectangle(L,A).
1*4-2*3=-2
3*6-4*5=-2
5*2-6*1=4
A = 0,
L = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: Consider using [format/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=format/2) instead of write/1.

Comment: Why write token after token instead of one arithmetic expression like `A*D-B*C=S1`?